# Add random integer token to log in URL

Tags: 7, tokens

I noticed that users are able to log in via `/user/login/[any random characters]`, thanks to a comment on a previous post of mine about [users not being able to log in some times](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/219847/users-cant-log-in-sometimes).

Is there a way to add the random:integer token to the log in URL? I tried simply creating a link to `/user/login/[random:integer]` but that didn't work; it generated exactly that link in the browser.

Comment: By doing that what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: I want to create a unique URL for the log in because of caching issues.